# displaying the output in Ouput windows in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, output

I'm debugging the c++ console application in visual studio 2015 but output is not displaying in debug output window.

```
    std::ostringstream buffer;
    std::cout << "\n result: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        buffer << array[i] << ",";
    }
    buffer << "\n";
```

In the output there are some warnings Cannot find or open the PDB file but it may not be reason.
What is the problem ?

Comment: How are we to know? [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display in MSVC debug output you need to use `::OutputDebugString()`.

eg `::OutputDebugString( buffer.str() );`